# div container does not float next to another one

Tags: html, css

The div element "rightsidecontainer" should float next to the "centralcontainer"
but does not happen..What is the reason?

```css
.centralcontainer {
  width: 78%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.rightsidecontainer {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="centralcontainer"></div>
<div class="rightsidecontainer"></div>
```

Comment: I put your code in a stack snippet and it seems fine

Comment: Also fine here.

Comment: Yea its working.

Comment: If you want it to be to the right of the `centralcontainer` you can just assign `float: left;` to your `.rightsidecontainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to add float:left to the .rightsidecontainer too.

```css
.centralcontainer {
  width: 78%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.rightsidecontainer {
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="centralcontainer"></div>
<div class="rightsidecontainer"></div>
```

Comment: Yes. You can float an unlimited number of elements side by side but you do need to set “float:” direction for each. If your floated elements are longer than the view window they’ll bump down and create a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline-block also instead of adding the float property:

```
.centralcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 78%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.rightsidecontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  height: 100px;
}
```